# How to subclass UTexture2D?

Tags: c++, macos, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to create subclass from `UTexture2D` to have it working with Apple's `CVPixelBufferRef`. I use `AppleARKitTextures.h` as example and just replaced `UTexture` with `UTexture2D`.

When I try to compile my module, I get this error:

```
CompilerResultsLog: [3/6] Compile Module.MyCameraModule.gen.cpp
CompilerResultsLog: [1/6] Compile MyCameraModule.cpp
CompilerResultsLog: [2/6] Compile Module.MyCameraModule.cpp
CompilerResultsLog: [4/6] Link UE4Editor-MyCameraModule-0031.dylib
CompilerResultsLog: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
CompilerResultsLog:   "UTexture2D::PreSave(ITargetPlatform const*)", referenced from:
CompilerResultsLog:       vtable for UAppleCameraTexture in Module.MyCameraModule.cpp.o
CompilerResultsLog:   "UTexture2D::PostLoad()", referenced from:
CompilerResultsLog:       vtable for UAppleCameraTexture in Module.MyCameraModule.cpp.o

...

CompilerResultsLog:   "UTexture2D::CalcTextureMemorySizeEnum(ETextureMipCount) const", referenced from:
CompilerResultsLog:       vtable for UAppleCameraTexture in Module.MyCameraModule.cpp.o
CompilerResultsLog:   "UTexture2D::Serialize(FArchive&)", referenced from:
CompilerResultsLog:       vtable for UAppleCameraTexture in Module.MyCameraModule.cpp.o
CompilerResultsLog:   "vtable for UTexture2D", referenced from:
CompilerResultsLog:       UAppleCameraTexture::UAppleCameraTexture(FObjectInitializer const&) in Module.MyCameraModule.cpp.o
CompilerResultsLog:       UAppleCameraTexture::~UAppleCameraTexture() in Module.MyCameraModule.cpp.o
CompilerResultsLog:       UAppleCameraTexture::UAppleCameraTexture(FVTableHelper&) in Module.MyCameraModule.gen.cpp.o
CompilerResultsLog:   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
CompilerResultsLog:   "FRenderAssetUpdate::Release() const", referenced from:
CompilerResultsLog:       UAppleCameraTexture::UAppleCameraTexture(FObjectInitializer const&) in Module.MyCameraModule.cpp.o
CompilerResultsLog:       UAppleCameraTexture::~UAppleCameraTexture() in Module.MyCameraModule.cpp.o
CompilerResultsLog:       UAppleCameraTexture::UAppleCameraTexture(FVTableHelper&) in Module.MyCameraModule.gen.cpp.o
CompilerResultsLog: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
CompilerResultsLog: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

With `UTexture` it compiles fine. I need to use `UTexture2D` because I plan to use this texture in UI.

Source code:

```
UCLASS( MinimalAPI, BlueprintType )
class UAppleCameraTexture : public UTexture2D, public IAppleImageInterface
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()

public:    
    // UTexture interface implementation
    virtual void BeginDestroy() override;
    virtual FTextureResource* CreateResource() override;
    virtual EMaterialValueType GetMaterialType() const override { return MCT_Texture2D; }
    virtual float GetSurfaceWidth() const override { return Size.X; }
    virtual float GetSurfaceHeight() const override { return Size.Y; }
    // End UTexture interface

#if PLATFORM_MAC || PLATFORM_IOS
    /** Sets any initialization data */
    virtual void Init(float InTimestamp, CVPixelBufferRef InCameraImage);

    /** Queues the conversion on the render thread */
    virtual void Init_RenderThread();

    /** Store off the camera image for a later resource update */
    void EnqueueNewCameraImage(CVPixelBufferRef InCameraImage);
#endif

    virtual EAppleTextureType GetTextureType() const override { return EAppleTextureType::PixelBuffer; }

#if PLATFORM_MAC || PLATFORM_IOS
    /** Returns the cached camera image. You must retain this if you hold onto it */
    CVPixelBufferRef GetCameraImage() const { return CameraImage; }

    // IAppleImageInterface interface implementation
    virtual CVPixelBufferRef GetPixelBuffer() const override { return CameraImage; }
    // End IAppleImageInterface interface
#endif

private:

    float Timestamp;
    FGuid ExternalTextureGuid;
    FVector2D Size;

#if PLATFORM_MAC || PLATFORM_IOS
    /** The Apple specific representation of the ar camera image */
    CVPixelBufferRef CameraImage;
    CVPixelBufferRef NewCameraImage;
    FCriticalSection PendingImageLock;
#endif
};
```